# Can't write image data to path - Intervention Image

Tags: php, laravel, intervention

I'm trying to resize my images using [Intervention](http://image.intervention.io) package in my laravel project. I'm able to store images using Storage facade, but when I store them with Image class it throws below error.

> Can't write image data to path
>   (/var/www/commerce/storage/featureds/2-1537128615.jpg)

```
if ($request->has("featured_img")) {
    $file_path = $request->get("featured_img");
    $exp = explode("/",$file_path);
    $filename = $exp[1];
    $featured_path = "featureds/".$filename;
    \Storage::copy($request->get("featured_img"), $featured_path);

    \Image::make(\Storage::get($featured_path))->fit(400, 300)->save(storage_path($featured_path));
    $product->media()->where("type", "featured")->update(["path" => $featured_path]);

 }
```

How can I fix this ? Thanks for all your helps

Comment: 1. Does the directory exist? 'featureds'? 2. Does your PHP script have permission to write to that directory?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware yes it does

Answer (score 0):

Is there **featureds** directory in **storage**?

If no, you use **mkdir** to create directory because Intervention don't create directory automatically.

Comment: I have featureds folder under storage directory